# How to place the multiline cursor at end of each line but at the position in each line?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I want to place hyphen at the end of each line. I know I can do that by pressing Shift+Alt button in windows(to enable multiline cursors) and then jump to the end of line. (shown in the image below)
[image]

However, I want to place the cursor(and therefore hyphen) at the same position. In other words, I want hyphen to be below each another. Here is the pic of what I want -

[image]

Is there anyway to do this in vscode using multi-line shortcuts ?

Why do I want this ? To increase readability of my code.

Comment: There are a bunch of `align` extensions that do this sort of thing.  It is a pain to do it manually but can be done.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840718/9938317