# Insert Code Section in Visual Studio Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

In RStudio when I use the short cut `CTRL+SHIFT+R` and type `LABEL` and I get the following

```
# LABEL -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I use Spyder I can use the short cut `CTRL+SHIFT+H`

```
# =============================================================================
# LABEL
# =============================================================================
```

Is there an equivalent in Visual Studio Code

Comment: use snippets or use the extension **Hypersnips** if you want to madify the `=====` parts based on the entered text: `80-text.length`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58711715/how-to-create-a-comment-block-of-s-around-text-of-different-lengths/58722958#58722958 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840667/add-different-number-of-spaces-to-multiple-lines-so-that-each-line-has-equal-amo/73840861#73840861 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56869050/how-to-pad-out-line-to-certain-length-using-regex-replace-and-snippets/56874352#56874352